# Get all commit or changes by GitHub release/tag

Tags: git, github

I've been trying to get all GitHub commits or changes by the GitHub release/tag, I did get the tag API back, but I need go fetch each commit.url to see all commit, but require keep fetching to get data back, I wonder is anyway I can just get the changes/commit by release/tag API call?

I also thought maybe I pull commit API `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits` get `sha` or `node_id` to filter tag API, but none of their number match.

**Currently workflow:**

1. `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/tags`
2. Response

```
[
  {
    "name": "v0.1",
    "commit": {
      "sha": "c5b97d5ae6c19d5c5df71a34c7fbeeda2479ccbc",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits/c5b97d5ae6c19d5c5df71a34c7fbeeda2479ccbc"
    },
    "zipball_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/zipball/v0.1",
    "tarball_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/tarball/v0.1"
  }
]
```

2. I use that `commit.url` to fetch the commit, but sometime have nesting commit by `parents`, more commit each single URL.

Sample:

```
 "parents": [
      {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
        "sha": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called "revision walking", and the GitHub API is not a good way to do it.  As you've discovered, it's highly inefficient to ask about each commit and then its parents, and so on.

If you need to do revision walking, or any other sort of mass mining of commits, the best way to go about that is to clone the repository locally and perform the operations on your local system.  That's much faster and more efficient, and it won't result in you getting rate-limited by the GitHub API.